# Why receiving mail at address is important legal factor?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

I've seen several times on this site and elsewhere (and on one of [my own questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/36813/24135)) that when it comes to housing questions/disputes often it's being asked "Have you received mail addressed to you at this address ?" Why is that a significant factor ? What does it legally prove or disprove ?

Context: US law

Answer (score 3):

It is legally significant because you have certain protections from eviction is you reside in a place. If you are just a weekend guest (or an uninvited intruder), you don't enjoy tenant privileges and could be arrested by the police for trespassing. Whereas if you have been living in a house for some months, then removing you from your residences is typically a more involved legal procedure. Receiving mail at an address over a period of time is evidence that you reside there.